# ls -F OR ls -al - What does the red highlighting mean?

Tags: linux, security, ls

So I ran a `ls -F` or `ls -al` on my `/usr/bin` directory and some of my files showed up with a red background and white text.  What does this mean?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the GNU implementation of `ls`, the meaning of the colours depends on the setting of the `LS_COLORS` environment variable, typically set up with the [`dircolors`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dircolors) command.

A (combination of) numeric code(s) determines which colours get used to indicate a particular file type:

```
# Attribute codes:
# 00=none 01=bold 04=underscore 05=blink 07=reverse 08=concealed
# Text color codes:
# 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
# Background color codes:
# 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
```

A white text on a red background is defined with a combination of `37;41`

Use `echo "$LS_COLORS"` to investigate and find that:
 `su=37;41`
thus SETUID files are white text on a red background (which happens to be the default)

`dircolors --print-database` gives a more verbose and readable output for the default settings in absence of any customisation:

```
SETUID 37;41 # file that is setuid (u+s)
STICKY 37;44 # dir with the sticky bit set (+t) and not other-writable
```

The only other default usage for a red highlight is **blue text** on a red background for directories with the sticky bit set.

Answer (score 4):

When you run an `ls -al` or `ls -F`, files listed with a red background and white text indicate that the `setuid` bit has been flipped. Meaning that the file/script/program will run as the user that owns it, not the user that ran it. As you can see from the picture, the `ping` and `ping6` have their 4th bit set as `s`, whereas the others, where the `setuid` bit has not been flipped, show an `x`.

[image]

Further information can be found at:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid